# Вывод в .php фаил данных из базы limesurvey v5.6.40 из зашифрованного вопроса

Tags: php, mysql

В limesurvey v5.6.40 можно вывести ответы респондента из таблички запросом вроде
`select id, submitdate, 111111X1X1SQ001 where submitdate is not null;` и данные выводятся корректно.
Если установлено шифрование в настройках вопроса 111111X1X1SQ001 то выводится зашифрованная абракадабра.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
`select id, submitdate, AES_DECRYPT(111111X1X1SQ001 , 'key') where submitdate is not null;`
ситуацию не спасает.

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result )){
sodium_crypto_secretbox_open($row['111111X1X1SQ001'],$nonce,$key)
    }
```

с ключем и нонсом из конфига limesurvey вызывает ошибку

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SodiumException: sodium_crypto_secretbox_open(): Argument #2 ($nonce) must be SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETBOX_NONCEBYTES bytes long in

Есть ли какой-то способ расшифровать такие данные и показать их корректно не только в админке limesurvey но и в .php файле через mysqli_query()?

попробовал расшифровать ключ и нонс как тут

https://github.com/LimeSurvey/LimeSurvey/blob/4139afef7446f37e8a3bc2dfd9ce2423f8265d8a/application/core/LSSodium.php#L64

```
sodium_crypto_secretbox_open($row['111111X1X1SQ001'],sodium_hex2bin('nonce'),sodium_hex2bin('key'))
```

Ошибок нет, значение не расшифровывается, нет записей в error.log Апача, статус запроса скрипта 200, переменная пустая.

Расшифровывал переменную Имя.
[image: Расшифровывал переменную Имя.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Финальное решение, которое сработало:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result )){
            echo( 
  sodium_crypto_secretbox_open(base64_decode($row['111111X1X1SQ001']),sodium_hex2bin('$nonce'),sodium_hex2bin('$key'))

   );
}
```

расшифровывает и выводит корректный текст для каждой зашифрованной записи из базы данных с  нонсом и ключём из файла secure.php